# java JFrame Keylistener and Images what am i doing wrong?

Tags: java, image, jframe, keylistener

Im just programming a game but something is not working heres the main code(Where the keylistener is (and JFrame))

```
package two.game.first.windows;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import two.game.first.windows.OpenLoad;
import two.game.first.help.Images;
import two.game.first.help.Images.dir;
import two.game.first.help.Data;

public class Game{

public static JFrame f = new JFrame();
private static int width = OpenLoad.width;
private static int height = OpenLoad.height;
private static String map=null, save=null;
private static String p = OpenLoad.path;
public static boolean paused = false;
public static HashMap<String, String> blocks = new HashMap<String, String>();
private static File mapf;


//X IS ALWAYS FIRST IN THE FILES!!!

public Game(File map) throws IOException{
    this.map = map.getName();
    this.mapf = map;
    start();
}
public Game(File map, File save) throws IOException{
    this.map = map.getName();
    this.save = save.getName();
    this.mapf = map;
    start();

}
private static void start(){
    f.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
                Images.reDraw(blocks, dir.UP);
                System.out.println("up key");
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
                Images.reDraw(blocks, dir.RIGHT);
                System.out.println("right key");
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
                Images.reDraw(blocks, dir.DOWN);
                System.out.println("down key");
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
                Images.reDraw(blocks, dir.LEFT);
                System.out.println("left key");
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
                pause();
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_E){
                try {
                    Data.save(mapf, blocks);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
                Images.reDraw(blocks, dir.UP);
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
                Images.reDraw(blocks, dir.RIGHT);
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
                Images.reDraw(blocks, dir.DOWN);
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
                Images.reDraw(blocks, dir.LEFT);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }
    });

    f.setSize(width, height);
    if (save == null){
        f.setTitle("RofsGame - "+map);
    }else{
        f.setTitle("RofsGame - "+map+" - "+save);
    }
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    File f = new File("apple.jpg");
    Images.draw(f, 10, 10, blocks);
    OpenLoad.close();
    Menu.close();
    try {
        Data.get(blocks, mapf);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void pause(){
    if (paused){
        paused = false;
    }else{
        paused = true;
    }

}
public static void close(){
    f.dispose();
}
}
```

And here is the other class (images (and moving the images))

```
package two.game.first.help;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import two.game.first.windows.Game;

public class Images {

public static void draw(File file, int x, int y, HashMap<String, String> saves){
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(file.getPath());
    String name = file.getName();
    JLabel imgs = new JLabel(img);
    imgs.setBounds(x, y, img.getIconWidth(), img.getIconHeight());
    imgs.setLocation(x, y);
    imgs.setVisible(true);
    Game.f.add(imgs);
    imgs.setVisible(true);
    saves.put(x+"_"+y, name);
}
public static void reDraw(HashMap<String, String> saves, int x, int y){
    Game.f.getContentPane().removeAll();
    for (Entry<String, String> e : saves.entrySet()){
        String img = e.getValue();
        String[] help = e.getKey().split("_");
        int ox = Integer.parseInt(help[0]), oy = Integer.parseInt(help[1]);
        File f = new File(img);
        if (!f.exists()){
            return;
        }
        ImageIcon imgi = new ImageIcon(img);
        JLabel l = new JLabel(imgi);
        l.setBounds(x, y, imgi.getIconWidth(), imgi.getIconHeight());
        l.setLocation(x, y);
        l.setVisible(true);
        Game.f.add(l);
        saves.remove(ox+"_"+oy);
        saves.put(x+"_"+y, f.getName());
    }
}

public static void reDraw(HashMap<String, String> saves, dir d){
    if (saves.isEmpty() || saves == null){
        return;
    }
    HashMap<String, String> asd = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Game.f.getContentPane().removeAll();
    for (Entry<String, String> e : saves.entrySet()){
        if (saves.isEmpty()){
            return;
        }
        String img = e.getValue();
        File f = new File(img);
        if (!f.exists()){
            return;
        }
        String[] help = e.getKey().split("_");
        int ox = Integer.parseInt(help[0]), oy = Integer.parseInt(help[1]);
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon(img);
        JLabel l = new JLabel(i);
        switch(d){
        case LEFT:  
            x = ox+200;
            l.setBounds(x, oy, i.getIconWidth(), i.getIconHeight());
            l.setLocation(x, oy);
            l.setVisible(true);
            Game.f.add(l);
            l.setVisible(true);
            asd.put(x+"_"+oy, f.getName());
        case RIGHT:
            x = ox-200;
            l.setBounds(x, oy, i.getIconWidth(), i.getIconHeight());
            l.setLocation(x, oy);
            l.setVisible(true);
            Game.f.add(l);
            l.setVisible(true);
            asd.put(x+"_"+oy, f.getName());
        case UP:
            y = oy+200;
            l.setBounds(ox, y, i.getIconWidth(), i.getIconHeight());
            l.setLocation(ox, y);
            l.setVisible(true);
            Game.f.add(l);
            l.setVisible(true);
            asd.put(ox+"_"+y, f.getName());
        case DOWN:
            y = oy-200;
            l.setBounds(ox, y, i.getIconWidth(), i.getIconHeight());
            l.setLocation(ox, y);
            l.setVisible(true);
            Game.f.add(l);
            l.setVisible(true);
            asd.put(ox+"_"+y, f.getName());
        }
    }
    saves.clear();
    saves = asd;
}

public static enum dir{
    LEFT,RIGHT,UP,DOWN;
}
}
```

And btw i've tried putting a try{}catch(){} loop at the keylistener but i dont get an error there!

Comment: Can you describe what is not working?

Comment: What i am working on is when the user presses a key on the keyboard all imges will move in the direction he pressed.

Comment: For a long shot you can try to invoke "repaint()" on the frame or the specific container of the elements you want to move.

Comment: What do you mean with invoke?